# Why is this if statement not working on my windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm making a tic tac toe game but its 8x8 instead of 3x3 on click the selected button changes to an image of a black or red dot. On the check for winner function I would think that putting the following code would immediately pop up "Winner" after both H4 and H5 were both checked as black, but nothing happens.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    p1Turn.Checked = true;
}

public void CheckForWinner()
{
    if (H4.Image == Properties.Resources.black2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Winner");
    }
}

public void PlayerTurn()
{
    if (p1Turn.Checked == true)
    {
        p1Turn.Checked = false;
        p2Turn.Checked = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        p2Turn.Checked = false;
        p1Turn.Checked = true;
    }
}

private void A1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (A1.Image == null)
    {
        if (p1Turn.Checked == true)
        {
            A1.Image = Properties.Resources.black2;
        }
        else
        {
            A1.Image = Properties.Resources.red_2;
        }
        PlayerTurn();
    }
}

private void A2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (A2.Image == null)
    {
        if (p1Turn.Checked == true)
        {
            A2.Image = Properties.Resources.black2;
        }
        else
        {
            A2.Image = Properties.Resources.red_2;
        }
        PlayerTurn();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can post all the code if it helps clarify things

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. The form loads up and everything works EXCEPT for the Check for winner

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of your if line.

Comment: did that, nothing happened

Comment: @Amon it completely changes the logic of the code, so something *must* have changed after removing the `;`. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Based upon the code shown, I would say your CheckForWinner function isn't being called, or you are doing something that causes an exception and the if not to be fully evaluated.  The `;` after the if and before the `{` is a problm, but it would cause "Winner" to always show, not never show.

Comment: What is the type of `H4` & `H5`?

Comment: Agree with jmoreno.  CheckForWinner isn't being called.  If it was, when you first ran it with the semicolon, you would have always seen the MessageBox.Show.  Alternatively, there is something preventing MessageBox.Show from showing.

Comment: @Amon - you wrote *I can post all the code if it helps clarify things*.  Please try to create a [minimal but complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem, then edit your question to include it, otherwise we're just guessing what the problem is.

Comment: i'll happily send you a zip if you need more clarification

Comment: @Enigmativity what exactly are you referring to when you say type?

Comment: Amon Your code *never* calls `CheckForWinner`

Comment: @Amon - besides not calling `CheckForWinner`, your code never set `H4.Image` in your question.  To give relevant answers, we need to see a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem -- one that provides *all parts needed to reproduce the problem*.  Otherwise we're kind of guessing.

Comment: @Amon - The CLR type, i.e. `H4.GetType()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While setting the image, set the tag property of H4 and H5 with a relevant string tag as follows.

```
H4.Tag = "black2";
H5.Tag = "black2";
```

Then compare tag properties in the if statement as below.

```
if (H4.Tag == "black2" && H5.Tag == "black2")
{

    MessageBox.Show("Winner");
}
```

Comment: added those, nothing happens. I'm not trying to be a downer. It just makes ZERO sense to me that having "H4.Image == Properties.Resources.black2" isn't good enough

Answer (score 4):

Remove **";"** , Write the below code..

```
 if ((H4.Image == Properties.Resources.black2) && (H5.Image == Properties.Resources.black2))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Winner");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are checking reference equality of images returned by repeated calls to the property `Properties.Resources.black2`:

```
    if (H4.Image == Properties.Resources.black2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Winner");
    }
```

Unfortunately, every time you fetch an image resource from resources, *the resource manager may create a new instance of the image*.  You can check this by simply doing:

```
    var same = (Properties.Resources.black2 == Properties.Resources.black2);
    Console.WriteLine(same); // Prints False
```

Thus you cannot use image resource values for remembering state information for your program, and must use something else, like the [tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170890/why-is-this-if-statement-not-working-on-my-windows-form/34171167#34171167).

For confirmation, see the documentation for [`ResourceManager.GetObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963f81yd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If you call the GetObject method multiple times with the same name parameter, do not depend on the method returning a reference to the same object with each call. This is because the GetObject method can return a reference to an existing resource object in a cache, or it can reload the resource and return a reference to a new resource object.